# Disable or Remove Customer Account

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am working on the Customer Templates Logic in Shopify.

I cannot find a way in Liquid for a Customer to remove his/ her account.

I have been going through the Template Forms but cannot find the code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Shopify customers can't delete their own accounts like close accounts or something similar.

But at the same time you can delete the customer from backend sections, so you if need this feature then you need to create a private APP that interacts with API and allow the customer to delete their own account.

Here is the useful Shopify forum thread [link](https://community.shopify.com/c/Technical-Q-A/Method-to-Remove-customer-account-using-shopify-API/td-p/763383)
discussing the same feature or issue.

I hope it will provide you a clear view regarding it.